# Woocommerce - Retrieve shipping class

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

I use following code on external script to retrieve all products (simple and variable):

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => array('product', 'product_variation'),
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    $shop_products = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($shop_products as $item) {
        echo $item->ID.": shipping class is -> ".$item->get_shipping_class()."<br>";
    }
```

I need to create a list of product with their own shipping class, but it doesn't works.
It shows me the error "**Call to undefined method WP_Post::get_shipping_class()**".

What is wrong? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your code. Try following ---

```
$args = array(
        'post_type'   => array('product', 'product_variation'),
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );
    $shop_products = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ($shop_products as $item) {
        $product = wc_get_product($item->ID);
        echo $item->ID.": shipping class is -> ".$product->get_shipping_class()."<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Hi Alice. :-( unfortunately your solution doesn't works to me. I use Wordpress 4.7.4 and Woocommerce 2.6.14.

I've also tryed with:

    foreach ($shop_products as $item) {
        $product = new WC_Product($item->ID);
        echo $item->ID.": shipping class is -> ".$product->get_shipping_class()."<br>";
    }

but it also doesn't works.

Comment: Ok. I've solved. It was my fault 'cause I've passed "$items->ID" instead of "$item->ID". Your solution works. Thanks Alice. :-)